SDL2 не распознает все оси пульта
SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
mJoystick = SDL_JoystickOpen (0);

в итоге
SDL_JoystickNumAxes (mJoystick) == 7

А всего 4 тумблера. Три из которых работает корректно, а 4ый (8ая ось) не видит.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
